# Saving memory in php objects

Tags: php, oop, optimization, scope

I have a class in php with a method similar to the two below. I am wondering what is the most optimal way to write this class? I need to use the disp_info method a lot and would like to know if it is wiser to place $message1 and $message2 outside of the function and call it in so I would not have to generate a new message every time or the other way around.

```
class Person(){
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $sex;
    public $result;

    public function disp_info(){
        $message1= "Hello my name is : ";
        $message2= "And my age is :";
        $this->result= $message1.$this->name.$message2.$this->age;
    }

    $this->disp_name();
}

class Person(){
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $sex;
    public $result;
    public $message1= "Hello my name is : ";
    public $message2= "And my age is :";

    public function disp_info(){
        $message1 = $this->message1
        $message2 = $this->message2
        $this->result = $message1.$this->name.$message2.$this->age;
    }

    $this->disp_name();
}
```

Thanks, 
Please enlighten me

Comment: You should follow the architecture, not the "optimization". Which is most suitable from your app design perspective?

Comment: Does Static variables help you?

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: well actually, message1 and message2 are suppose to be html tags like <span style='------'></span> so if I were to follow architecture, method1 would seem to be favorable to me and other developers. I think.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason for using static variables in a class. It even somehow contradicts the whole concept of classes.
Generally, you better won't use the first method.
About optimization - the different would be measured in ms , the question is about which method would run faster - you could easly run a test and measure runtime of both methods.

Comment: 1. Please point to a static variables in the question. 2. OP mentioned memory consumption optimization, and said nothing about speed optimization.